# Only getting the last entered value when storing a value in sessionStorage.setitem

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, storage, stringify

Okay lets say i enter these two values in my HTML page: 20, 30.

I have these two variabels, i get the value from my HTML page, and it works fine, so BrugerFugt=20, and BrugerTemp=30:

```
    BrugerFugt = document.getElementById("40").value;
    BrugerTemp = document.getElementById("41").value;
```

Then i take these two variabels and use setItem.

```
    sessionStorage.setItem("BF", JSON.stringify(BrugerFugt));
    sessionStorage.setItem("BT", JSON.stringify(BrugerTemp));
```

At this point if i console.log(JSON.stringify(BrugerFugt)), it's printing 20, as it should.

Now i want to send this to my server, so i call this variable:

```
  serverConnection.send(JSON.stringify(SetBruger));
```

I have defined this variable, that i'm sending to my server.

```
var SetBruger = {
    command: "BrugerIndtastTF",
    brugerT: sessionStorage.getItem("BT"),
    brugerF: sessionStorage.getItem("BF")
}
```

Then i tryed to print my JSON.stringify(SetBruger), but it's printing the last value i entered on my HTML web, not the new. Let's say before i entered 20 and 30, i entered somthing like 40 and 60. Then when i print my SetBruger after i've entered 20 and 30, i get this print in my termiinal.

```
test: {"command":"BrugerIndtastTF","brugerT":"\"40\"","brugerF":"\"60\""}
```

It's like the problem occurs, when i JSON.stringify(SetBruger)?

Comment: Where/when in your program flow are all these things happening?  Like, is it possible you don’t call setStorage before sending that thing to the server?  Or, possibly you create the SetBruger variable somewhere and expect it to automatically update itself later on (which it won’t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object-properties are set when the object is created.

```
var SetBruger = {
    command: "BrugerIndtastTF",
    brugerT: sessionStorage.getItem("BT"), // set when object is created
    brugerF: sessionStorage.getItem("BF") // set when object is created
}
```

You can wrap that object with an helper-function that updates the object prior return or replace it with a function that returns an freshly created object with the values from sessionStorage like this:

```
function SetBruger() {
  return {
    command: "BrugerIndtastTF",
    brugerT: sessionStorage.getItem("BT"),
    brugerF: sessionStorage.getItem("BF")
  }
}
serverConnection.send(JSON.stringify(SetBruger));
```

To be able to re-use that object and update other properties of it, a helper function that updates the two properties with the content of localstorage would be a good solution.

```
var SetBruger = {
    command: "BrugerIndtastTF",
    brugerT: sessionStorage.getItem("BT"), // set when object is created
    brugerF: sessionStorage.getItem("BF") // set when object is created
}

// Other code that maybe modify the object

function updateBrugerObject() {
    SetBruger.brugerT = sessionStorage.getItem("BT");
    SetBruger.brugerF = sessionStorage.getItem("BF");
}

updateBrugerObject();
serverConnection.send(JSON.stringify(SetBruger));
```

what the best solution for you is, depends on how and where you plan to use the object.